# Where to put the TDataSource component?

Tags: delphi

When I split code into TDataModule (=access data) and TFom (=display data), where should I put the TDataSource component? Does it belong to the TDataModule or TForm?

And how to handle connenctions between the TDataModule and TForm, when multiple instances are created?

Comment: I believe you should put the datasource into the Form, and then assign multiple controls to that datasource. Later, at designtime or runtime, you set the datasource.dataset property. This then allows you to link the datasource to the dataset with one line of code, or even at designtime.  Otherwise, you would have to link each control to a common target outside the unit, which would be problematic and more difficult to maintain or change.   Since the datasource.dataset value at designtime in my apps is sometimes different than the runtime value, this goes double for my own apps.

Answer (score 10):

I would put the `Datasources` in the Form, since it is only a component to use with visual controls.

Also, you can create `Datasouces` on demand in the form when needed and bind then at runtime to the datasets. In that case it is easy to handle connections between the TDataModule and TForm.

But that's is just **MY** opinion: I would never use `DBControls` nor `DataSouces`. I prefer to bind my data by hand and have more flexibility than using `DBControls` and `DataSouces` and be stick to some weird mechanics Borland created. But that is just MHO.

Answer (score 1):

It is recomended to put your TDatasource components in the Form, but only if the data linked to them is only used by the parent form or any child of it.

Also is recommended to put your TDatasource components on a global TDatamodule when they are linked to global accesible data or list data, like a list of client, countries, etc. Data that may be used in more than one form in your application.

For example, if you have a `TDBLookupCombo`, the TDatasource assigned to `ListSource` property, is a good candidate to be on a TDatamodule.